# Issue in changing the name of flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have changed the **name** of my app in **AndroidManifest.xml** but it is showing the previous name that i used before changing.I tried by uninstalling the app but it did'nt work.

```
 <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Service Stop"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't forget to run:

```
flutter clean
```